# How to pass variable's values in multiline string shellscript

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I have a variable called `instdir` that has the current directory. I need to pass its value to a multiline string that will be written to a file. As `instdir` finishes with a slash I **can't** do anything like this:

```
cat > test <<EOF
  $instdir/final/path/to/file
EOF
```

But If I use `$instdirfinal` instead, it won't recognize the real `instdir`'s value. What I suppose to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the trick:

```
${instdir}final
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cat > test <<EOF
  ${instdir}final/path/to/file
EOF
```